# Sum new value and previous value of key in a dictionary

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following model Game <-->> AssistContribution. I have an array of games and array of assistContribution. An assistContribution have an assistCount and a PlayerName

I have to get all assists per game. I am going thru all assists per game and create a dictionary. I had the following logic, to create a dictionary which will have the player name and his totals assists count. Am wondering How could i make that when setting the dictionary after the 1st game, if the player have another assist count on the second game, it will adds up to the value of the previous game.

```
    func GetTotalAssist{
            print("Pressed")
            var dic : [String:Int] = [:]
           
           
            for game in games{
                guard let assists = game.assists?.array as? [AssistsContributions] else {return}
            
                for element in assists {
                    guard let playerName = element.joueurs?.name else { return }
                     let assistCount = element.assistsContribution
                  dic[(playerName)] = 0
//                dic[(playerName)]! += Int(assistCount)
                if dic[(playerName)] != nil {
                    dic[(playerName)]!  +=  Int(assistCount)
                } else {
                    dic[(playerName)]!  =  Int(assistCount)
                    }
                }
              print(dic)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the assist count to default to `0` for a player, and then you want to update that value for each game.  This is a perfect use case for the [`default:` parameter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2894528-subscript) of the dictionary lookup:

```
func GetTotalAssist{
    print("Pressed")
    var dic : [String:Int] = [:]
    
    for game in games {
        guard let assists = game.assists?.array as? [AssistsContributions] else {return}
        
        for element in assists {
            guard let playerName = element.joueurs?.name else { return }
            let assistCount = element.assistsContribution
            dic[playerName, default: 0] += Int(assistCount)
        }
        print(dic)
    }
}
```

The first time a new `playerName` is seen, it won't be present in the `dic`, so the `default:` value of `0` will be used.  If a value is present, then it will be retrieved.  In either case, the value will be increased by the new `assistCount`.  This will add the `playerName` to `dic` if it was not present before.

---

**Note:**  In both of your `guard` statement as written, they will return from the function as soon as they encounter a case where the `guard` fails.  A better thing to do here might be to just go to the next iteration of the `for` loop by replacing `return` with [`continue`](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html#ID135).

Comment: `guard let ... else { return }`. Might be an author mistake, but `continue` instead?

Comment: That's a good point, @Larme.  I wasn't looking at that part of the code.

Comment: Thanks. First time I see `Continue`. I will read on it.

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html#ID135